# How to assign the user command in VI(VIM)?

Tags: linux, command-line, vim, pdf

I'm trying to assign the user command in VI(VIM) in Linux(CentOS).

Especially, if there is one script(just text) file which is involved the pdf list file as the below, I want to view the each pdf file by using 'evince' command like as 'gf' command in linux. for example, If I put the cursor on the one of the pdf list, then If I push the function key, then the file which is listed in cursor is executed by using 'evince'.

If I want to see the 3.pdf, then I put the cursor then push the some function key then that pdf file is opened with evince. What am I supposed to do ?

How to assign the user command in VI(VIM)?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to customize Vim, you first build and test the commands manually, one by one. If you have a working sequence, you can easily define either *mappings* (that are triggered by a key [sequence], e.g. <kbd>F1</kbd>), or *commands* (typed in Ex mode, e.g. `:MyCommand`).

So, you need to read the current line and run a system command with it:

- Reading is straightforward with `y$` (you can use the lower-level `getline('.')` to avoid clobbering the default register, but that's an optional extension; first stick to the basics).
- System commands are `:! {cmd}` (again, there's a `system()` lower-level alternative)
- Inserting a register in *command-line mode* is `<C-r>"`.

(All of that can be found in the excellent `:help`.) The complete command would be (`<CR>` is the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key that concludes the command-line):

```
y$:! evince <C-r>"<CR>
```

If that works satisfactorily, you can turn it into a mapping, and put that into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:nnoremap <F1> y$:! evince <C-r>"<CR>
```

Voila! If you want to automatically progress to the next line, simply append a `j` at the end.